# Getting UiAutomator exited unexpectedly with code 0, signal null error

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

Getting UiAutomator exited unexpectedly with code 0, signal null error on appium version v1.10.0

My Appium server logs :- 
[image]

Comment: what are the desiredCapabilities that use used?

Comment: capabilities.SetCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");

Comment: what are the other capabilities you are using?

Comment: Appium Desktop 1.8.1 doesn't support "uiautomator2", not sure if it is fixed in 1.10.0. Try removing **automationName** from capabilities.

Comment: capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "android");
            capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "8.0");
            capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "Android 8.0");
            capabilities.SetCapability("noReset", true);
            // Application file path
            capabilities.SetCapability("app", "/Users/apple/Projects/AppiumTest/AppiumTest/APK/tvd-debug.apk");
            capabilities.SetCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
            capabilities.SetCapability("automationName", "UiAUtomator");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change Android version (I switch it to `Pie`)
2. Restart `Appium` server
3. Close and Re-open `AVD` device

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked for my case :) I was using R but I used Pie and worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the app was blocking further process. Due to some installed security features, immediately after app launch, all USB ports connections were refused by the app itself. After, the developers shared another apk with disabled security features, the test run was completed

Answer (score 0):

Seems like version issue... Ensure you have the latest sdk and it is updated for the Android version you are using.

Ensure that device is connected properly. At times the USB connection of not done correctly causes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Phone reboot worked for me. It's a process stuck on Android, at least that was it for me. You could also try
`adb shell ps | grep com.android.commands.monkey | awk '{print $2}' | xargs adb shell kill -9`
if you do not wish you reboot your phone.

Appium knows about this issue but closed it. I would recommend to move to Espresso for less headaches. Appium is and always will be a beta-state.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a cable issue. Try changing cables, too. Changing the automation name to `uiAutomator1` or `uiAutomator2` didn't make any difference, it was still failing. I even tried downloading Android SDK to match version 8, 9, 10.

My tests were running on 6 different real devices. The same script was running fine on 5 devices but throwing **uiAutomator stopped unexpectedly** for one device.

When I connected the same device with another cable it worked fine.

So when things go crazy, give a break, rethink, stop pulling hair. solution might be super simple.